# Reformat php array posted from a form with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a form on my website that sends the captured values of the form to an email address with php. On the form there is an checkbox input where users can select multiple checkboxes and the selected values are pushed into an array. When I submit the form the checkbox input returns an entire array in the email. To my understanding this is as far as php can reformat. I am looking for a way to reformat the php array with ajax to make it more reader friendly.

This is what the array looks like in the submitted email:

```
array ( 0 => 'value1', 1 => 'value2', 2 => 'value3' )
```

I am trying to make the array return the values in a different format such as:

```
Array Value:  value1, value2, value3
```

Here is my form:

```
  <form id="form" method="post" action="/submit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
     <label for="categoryType">Category type:</label>
     <input  type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value1">
     <label>value1</label>
     <input  type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value2">
     <label>value2</label>
     <input  type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value3">
     <label>value3</label>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Here is the submit.html:

```
<?php

  $check_list  = $this->EE->input->post(['check_list']);

  $msg .= '<p><strong>Category</strong> '.$value.'</p>';

    ob_start();
    var_dump($check_list);
    $result = ob_get_clean();


   $this->EE->email->wordwrap = true;
   $this->EE->email->mailtype = 'html';
   $this->EE->email->to('email@emailcom');
   $this->EE->email->subject('form');
   $this->EE->email->message(entities_to_ascii($msg . " - " . $result));
   $this->EE->email->Send();

    if($http_code > 200) {
     print "<p><strong>Error</strong> </p>";
   } else {
     header( 'Location: redirecturl' ) ;
   }
?>
```

Is there a way to show only the string values of the array by submitting the form with ajax? Or is there a different way to reformat this php array? Do I need to submit this form with php or could I scratch this method and only submit with ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
ob_start();
var_dump($check_list);
$result = ob_get_clean();
```

Try

```
$result = implode(',', $check_list);
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much @michael, that was way less complex than I was expecting, but works like a charm. That was exactly the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I did make one edit. I included a space after the comma `$result = implode(', ', $check_list);`  just for easier readability.